# Gateway failover

Tags: networking, failover, gateway, isp

I have an Ubuntu server acting as a gateway for inbound internet connections. This server shut down unexpectedly because of overheating and lost all internet connections during business hours. How can I implement a fail-over on a back-up server that I have, meaning that if the gateway shuts down, the two ISPs that I have go directly to this back-up server with as little downtime as possible? The back-up server has the same configuration and hardware as the gateway.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Router redundancy protocol like VRRP or CARP. Which are virtual routers that coordinate which physical host will respond to neighbor discovery. In other words, clustering methods for a virtual IP address.

Dynamic routing protocols are also possible. However, it can be an operational challenge to get hosts to speak your IGP.

Comment: here's a VRRP example also replicating firewall state: https://backreference.org/2013/04/03/firewall-ha-with-conntrackd-and-keepalived/ .